# Implement conversion operator without temporary

Tags: c++

I have a class Bob, which I can convert to another class BigClass. BigClass has an expensive constructor, but it is reasonably efficient to assign an existing BigClass a new state.

I have existing code which uses BigClass in a way like the following (contrived sample code)

```
vector<BigClass> data;
BigClass x;
for (vector<BigClass>::const_iterator it = data.begin(), end_it = data.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    x = *it;
    ...
}
```

The same BigClass instance is reused to speed things up inside the loop.

I want to change my source data structure to one of Bobs. I can define Bob as the following.

```
class Bob
{
public:
    BigClass operator() const
    {
        return BigClass(...);
    }
};
```

This will minimize changes to my code. However, each `x = *it` will result in an expensive temporary of BigClass being created.

Speed is important and gigabytes of data is being processed. I'm concerned this change will be too slow. (No I haven't profiled yet as I've not written it yet, but it already takes minutes to run).

If it's too slow, I'm considering the following:

```
class Bob
{
public:
    void Output(BigClass& x)
    {
        x = ...;
    }
};

vector<Bob> data;
BigClass x;
for (vector<Bob>::const_iterator it = data.begin(), end_it = data.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    it->Output(x);
    ...
}
```

But this will require more changes to the existing code, which is more work.

So my question is: is it possible to implement the conversion operator in a way that doesn't need to construct a new instance of the target type? I just need to assign new state to an existing instance.

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining why copy construction is significantly slower than copy assignment.

Comment: @MooingDuck Because assignment can reuse previously allocated resources.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's a good idea. Unfortunately BigClass is from a shared third-party library. But I can inherit from it and add the conversion!

Comment: @NeilKirk: (I deleted the comment since someone posted as answer already) Oh, you can't edit BigClass, but can derive from it?  That should probably be in the question.

Comment: Wrap the 'BigClass' in an own class and maintain the state - that way you get control of copy construction and assignment (you might even implement some caching)

Answer (score 3):

Although you cannot implement the conversion operator without making a temporary, you could solve this issue by altering `BigClass` to accept assignments from `Bob`:

```
class BigClass {
...
public:
    BigClass& operator=(const Bob& bob) {
        // Do the fast assignment
    }
};
```

Now the `x = *it` will compile without a special conversion operator.

Comment: Good idea! I can't modify BigClass, but I can inherit from it.

Comment: It begins to sound like the Adapter pattern.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following idea?

1. Maintain a `BigClass` object inside `class Bob`.
2. Return a constant reference to it from the conversion operator.
3. Change it every time the object is changed (i.e., in every non-constant member function).

---

```
class Bob
{
public:
    const BigClass& operator() const
    {
        return bigClass;
    }
private:
    BigClass bigClass;
};
```

Comment: I'd contemplate making the `bigClass` a thread-local variable instead of a member, and documenting it thouroughly